# How to append html element in current component?

Tags: javascript

I want append a html element in my current compnent like adding html element in document body using `document.body.appendChild(htmlElelmt)`.  I know using add div reference in my current component like `<div #container></div>` i can add element, But i actually want to add without using reference as it doesn't matter where the html element is being inserted.

Answer (score 1):

You must specify a reference, otherwise JavaScript doesn't know where to put the element.

You can make a function that chooses a random div to place it in.

```js
function addToPage(el) {
var elNo = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
document.querySelectorAll('.div'+elNo)[0].appendChild(el);
}
var myEl = document.createElement("SPAN");
myEl.innerText = "Hello, World!";
addToPage(myEl);
```

```html
<h4>DIV No. 1</h4>
<div class="div1"></div>
<h4>DIV No. 2</h4>
<div class="div2"></div>
<h4>DIV No. 3</h4>
<div class="div3"></div>
<h4>DIV No. 4</h4>
<div class="div4"></div>
```

Comment: You can also edit it to choose a random element: `docment.querySelectorAll('*')[elNo].appendChild(el);`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just add an element very top of the component, use `ElementRef`.

```js
import { Component, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

export class AppComponent  {
  constructor (elRef: ElementRef) {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    elRef.nativeElement.appendChild(div);
  }
}
```